# Accessing Attributes Of a Parent Table in Many To Many Realtionship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have two tables (Ansatt, Stilling) that are connected together through a separate table through Foreign keys (Ansatt_Stilling).
The new table allows connecting 1 Ansatt with One Stilling. The Stilling table has Start and En dates. The goal is that an Ansatt entity cannot have more than 1 Stilling entity simultaneously. So no overlapping. When the user inputs data in the Ansatt_Stilling table, I try to do so. The controller checks if there is an entry in that table where the Stilling has an overlapping start and end dates.

The Ansatt Model

```
public class Ansatt
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Navn { get; set; }

    //Relationships
    public virtual ICollection<Ansatt_Stilling> Ansatt_Stillinger { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ansatt_Oppgave> Ansatt_Oppgaver { get; set; }

}
```

The Stilling Model

```
public class Stilling
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Stilling_Navn { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Start_Dato { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Slutt_Dato { get; set; }

    // Relationships
    public virtual ICollection<Ansatt_Stilling> Ansatt_Stillinger { get; set; }
```

The Ansatt_Stilling Model

```
public class Ansatt_Stilling
{
    public int ansatt_id { get; set; }
    public int stilling_id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ansatt_id")]
    public virtual Ansatt Ansatt { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("stilling_id")]
    public virtual Stilling Stilling { get; set; }
}
```

The Ansatt_Stilling Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ansatt_id,stilling_id")] Ansatt_Stilling ansatt_Stilling)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            
            if (_context.Ansatt_Stillinger.Any(o => o.stilling_id == ansatt_Stilling.stilling_id) && _context.Ansatt_Stillinger.Any(o => o.ansatt_id == ansatt_Stilling.ansatt_id))
            {

                //ViewBag.Duplikat = "Ansatt allerede har en stilling i den perioden";
                ViewBag.Duplikat = "Allerede Registrert";
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                bool isOverlapping = _context.Ansatt_Stillinger.Any(v => v.Stilling.Start_Dato == ansatt_Stilling.Stilling.Start_Dato);
                ViewBag.Duplikat = " Start dato";
                _context.Add(ansatt_Stilling);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
        }
        ViewData["ansatt_id"] = new SelectList(_context.Ansatter, "Id", "Navn", ansatt_Stilling.ansatt_id);
        ViewData["stilling_id"] = new SelectList(_context.Stillinger, "Id", "Stilling_Navn", ansatt_Stilling.stilling_id);
        return View(ansatt_Stilling);
    }
```

What I want to do is something along the lines of

```
if (_context.Ansatt_Stillinger.Any(o => o.Stilling.Start_Dato== ansatt_Stilling.Stilling.Start_Dato))
```

Is there a way to have this type of access?

Comment: If you want to make ANSATT and STILLING table relation is 1-1, why you need to Ansatt_Stilling table? Add a column into Ansatt table which is named StillingID and connet Stilling table directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one, I hope it will help you to make better one;

```
public static bool isConflictWithAny(int ansatt_id, int stilling_id)
{
    var targetStilling = _context.Stilling.FirstOrDefult(x => x.Id == stilling_id);
    if (targetStilling == null) 
        return false;

    DateTime S = targetStilling.Start_Date;
    DateTime E = targetStilling.End_Date;

        
    return _context.Ansatt_Stillinger
           .Any(a=>
                a.ansatt_id == ansatt_id &&        // same ansatt
                a.stilling_id != stilling_id &&    // other stillings
              (
                // x < S  <  E  < z    insider
                (a.Stilling.StartDate <= S && E <= a.Stilling.EndDate) ||

                // S < x  <  E  < z    concurrent at last
                ( a.Stilling.StartDate <= E && a.Stilling.EndDate >= E) ||

                // x < S  <  z  < E    concurrent at first
                ( a.Stilling.StartDate <= S && a.Stilling.EndDate <= E) ||

                // S < x  <  z < E     outsider
                ( S <= a.Stilling.StartDate && a.Stilling.EndDate <= E)
              )
            );
}
```